# Как собрать в Delphi-проект с runtime bpl'кой на windows 10?

Tags: delphi, windows-10

Есть группа проектов, состоящая из одного проекта службы и нескольких проектов bpl. В древние времена всё работало, но на Win10 всё сломалось, служба просто зависает на этапе запуска. Было принято простое решение просто пересобрать её на на десятке в новой IDE, а не в древнем BDS2006.

Поставил RAD Studio 10, bpl собираются, но не выходит собрать саму службу, просит bdertl, которого нет. Нагуглил, что надо убрать флаг с "Link with runtime packages". Убрал, теперь не получается подключить собранную только что bpl, которая компилируется как "Only realtime". Пробовал её собирать как "Disign and realtime", тоже не помогло. Просит файл *.pas для этой bpl. Я уже и сам bpl положил рядом с ним, и dcu, и dpk, но он хочет pas.

При этом я крайне редко работаю с delphi, в основном шарп и иногда плюсы. Как мне собрать это?

Comment: Я попробовал установить значение "use MSBuild externally to compile" в true, что дало неоднозначные результаты. При сборке приложения со службой я получаю ошибку компиляции библиотеки bpl, что она не может найти модуль, объявленный в другой библиотеке bpl. Однако, если я собираю bpl'ки по отдельности, то это не вызывает никаких ошибок как с включённым "use MSBuild externally to compile", так и с выключенным.

Comment: "просит bdertl", гугл и два клика: https://forum.combit.net/t/vcl-package-with-embarcadero-rad-studio-xe7-and-higher/5114 , но вообще в 2019м стоит задуматься об отказе от BDE...

Comment: @Alekcvp, о, большое спасибо, это и правда помогло) Видимо, гугл и правда порой лучше яндекса.